# After update, Force Close for system resources not found

Tags: android

I don't know why. Install the package directly won't have any problem. But will fail because of Force Close if update the old package. the log is:

```
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:617)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:318)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1631)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.yidongsoft.ultraNoteEnhancedRegister.StartUI.setupWidgets(StartUI.java:237)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.yidongsoft.ultraNoteEnhancedRegister.StartUI.initialize(StartUI.java:129)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.yidongsoft.ultraNoteEnhancedRegister.StartUI.checkPassword(StartUI.java:591)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.yidongsoft.ultraNoteEnhancedRegister.StartUI.onCreate(StartUI.java:112)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1132)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     ... 11 more
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.<init>(ExpandableListView.java:198)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     ... 25 more
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-480x320/list_selector_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020005
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1625)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:160)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.<init>(ExpandableListView.java:202)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     ... 29 more
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-480x320/list_selector_background.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x7f020005
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1843)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1620)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     ... 32 more
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-480x320/list_selector_background.xml
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:471)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1825)
09-02 18:19:20.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1659):     ... 33 more
```

The file not found seems android embedded resources. Can any one explain why? I am using HTC Magic, official rom 1.5

Comment: what did you do to your old package while updating?

Comment: I didn't do anything to it. But I think one thing is important: I compile the package in Windows 7 instead of in my previous Ubuntu 9.10. I don't know whether this is a problem. There may be some other reason. For example, adt and SDK. I use 1.6 SDK in ubuntu 9.10, but in windows 7 I use xxx(I don't know which one I used, because I download all the sdk from 1.5 to 2.2 with setup.exe). Then just now I return to ubuntu 9.10 to compile the package, then nothing bad appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-480x320` just like `-hdpi`, `-ldpi`, `-mdpi` doesn't work in android 1.5.

Comment: I know that. Let's assume you got the real reason. But why the package is OK if you install the package directly, not update from old version? So sorry I didn't mention this in original post.

Comment: And, I don't use 480x320 in my drawables. I don't know why the log said this.

Comment: @Henry Sou: Are you compiling against > 3 and not setting targetVersion in your manifest?

Comment: No. I didn't set the targetVersion at all. About the SDK version, I only set:
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
But it was set long long ago.

Comment: what does it say on your default.properties file?

Comment: # This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
# 
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
# 
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system use,
# "build.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.

# Indicates whether an apk should be generated for each density.
split.density=false
# Project target.
target=android-4

Comment: split.density=false
target=android-4

Comment: You are building with android 1.6. Try changing it to android 1.5.

Comment: OK. Thanks! But I still don't know what the reason it is. Why will it say a system resource not found? Totally confused.

Comment: Stuff like `-480x320` doesn't work on android 1.5 so I guess you are using and android component that was modified in android 1.6 to support different screen sizes. And when it tries to look for `res/drawable-480x320/list_selector_background.xml` for example it will not find it.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar exception. In my case, I was giving `ListView`, divider attribute to "`@+id/empty`" which could not be found on Android 3.1 framework